# Does ADFS work with SSL offloading?

Tags: adfs

Does ADFS work with SSL offloading? Ive only seen ADFS with SSL certificates on the web servers, and we know it requires SSL. But does this requirement mean it must be all the way through to the servers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is no reason at all that you could not offload SSL to an encrypting reverse proxy or similar.  It is effectively an HTTP service like any other, and when you register it, it should be possible to cause it to listen only on http.

I don't believe it *requires* SSL, though implementing it without SSL would be extremely foolish.

That said, you do still need the token signing and encrypting/decrypting certificates, and you cannot offload that.

Comment: Without an encrypting reverse proxy, would it still work?  For example, if you have an F5 load balancer which alters the incoming https to ordinary port 80 http, and the web servers listen on port 80.

Comment: The way it "alters" it is by encrypting and decrypting it, so it is an encrypting reverse proxy (among other things) and it fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

ADFS requires that the certificates are on the federation and proxy servers. I just recently went through this. SSL offload isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

From this Microsoft document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-faq

- Load balancers MUST not terminate the HTTPS connections and reinitiate a new connection to the ADFS server.